# Are CVS-style checkout hooks possible in SVN?

Tags: svn, hook, cvs, svn-checkout

We are migrating from CVS to SVN and as far as I can see, SVN does not have checkout hooks. In CVS the post checkout operation is defined using the `-o` option when defining modules in the module file. Is this behavior possible in SVN?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Subversion Checkout Hook or something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804970/is-there-a-subversion-checkout-hook-or-something-similar). While this question was asked slightly earlier, [better questions and better answers are favored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/8117067), and the linked question has more substantive answers and more attention. In this case, a merge might be even better.

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify: What would you want to use *check-out* hooks for?

I've never really been a CVS user, so I do not know what common use-cases the solved (wanted to...) by using check-out hooks (actually I haven't known them).

SVN provides pre-commit and post-commit hooks (among some others), which should be able to do whatever one wants to be done per-change on the source.

If you need some automatic post-check-out processing on the working copy, you'll not have much other alternatives then writing a script, and remind the clients to execute them.

Answer (score -2):

Probably "alternatives" refers to "hooks" and not to SVN, but currently, I see a lot better systems to migrate to than SVN (e.g., Mercurial, Git)... even if one does not follow Linus Torvalds seeing '[Subversion as being the most pointless project ever started](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8)'..

Comment: When listening to Linus Torvalds, one should always wear appropriate filtering gear.