# Is there a Subversion Checkout Hook or something similar?

Tags: svn, hook, svn-checkout, svn-hooks

I'm using a subversion repository and I want to know whenever somebody asks my repository for a checkout; like a 'svn co' or an 'svn up'. Is there a hook or some other method that I can use so that a script is run, or email sent, whenever somebody requests information from my svn server? How can I achieve this without relying on apache logs?

BTW it is a pretty simple repository just meant for Educational purposes.

(If you need more information then just ask. Thanks in advance.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following are all the supported hooks in Subversion 1.5, from the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html) book:

- start-commit
- pre-commit
- post-commit
- pre-revprop-change
- post-revprop-change
- pre-lock
- post-lock
- pre-unlock
- post-unlock

There is no pre-checkout or pre-update hook like you describe.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using TortoiseSVN, you have access to [client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

Comment: +1 good solution if you need to control and manage the client configurations anyway, e.g. for autoprops settings

Answer (score 0):

You could do whatever you want using Apache as SVN server and (for example) mod_perl to hook into the requests. Maybe the log files already show the information you want.

SVN via SSH should also be possible: Analyze the commands started by the SVN client and wrap them (for example, by renaming the original binary with ".orig" extension and putting a (shell) script into that place.