# How to know who checked out the repository in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to know which users checked out a repository of an SVN Server?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804970/is-there-a-subversion-checkout-hook-or-something-similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you have access to apache logs(if you are using DavSVN)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure which distribution of SVN you’re using, but the Enterprise edition of [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) logs this activity to the Windows event log.