# any way to know how many checkouts of my code have happened from code.google.com?

Tags: svn, monitoring, tracking, google-code, svn-checkout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Subversion Checkout Hook or something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804970/is-there-a-subversion-checkout-hook-or-something-similar)

I have hosted the code for one of my projects on code.google.com. While I am able to monitor incoming traffic to my project page using google analytics, I do not find a way to track how many checkouts of my code have happened. Is there any way to find details on checkouts that are happening?