# Google Project Hosting: SVN statistics

Tags: svn, google-code

Is there any way to count downloads thru SVN checkout with Google's hosting?

Comment: NO there is not.

This question is already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100249/any-way-to-know-how-many-checkouts-of-my-code-have-happened-from-code-google-com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do it. In general, SVN does support commit hooks. Unfortunately, there's no hook for checkouts.

Comment: And the issue report on Google project hosting: http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=231