# How do I know who has checked out a file?

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-checkout

I'm looking to implement source control for my team. An external requirement that came up is that "managers/leads" want to know who has checked out which file and when. Not really a lock, they just want to know when a file was taken out and by who. It's also a show stopper requirement and is beyond my control.

I'm mainly looking at using Subversion. I figure if I use it through Apache, then I can parse the HTTP logs, unless there's already a tool for that, either 3rd party web log analysis tool or something directly created for subversion.

Any other popular source control tools that may have this kind of feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Subversion Checkout Hook or something similar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804970/is-there-a-subversion-checkout-hook-or-something-similar)

Comment: It sounds like your managers want to know who is actively working on a given file. Without using locking, I don't see how you can get an accurate record of this. Everyone who is working on a given project will probably have the file checked out into their local repository, even if they aren't actively working on every file.

Comment: That's another story I have to convince them about! That a software project is not just one file. Yes my life is complicated! lol

Comment: There are good answers in that dupe link, but the short answer is you can't, because "checking out" a file in subversion is a no-op (Perforce on the other hand has a checkout operation that communicates with the server). A user simply edits any file he likes in his local repository, and when it's time to commit changes back to the server, only the files that have been changed will be transmitted. Instead of the managers tracking who has "checked out a file", perhaps instead they could track "who is working on a task" -- i.e. use some project/task tracking tool for this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I as a developer would feel a certain discomfort but what your "managers" want is a client-based "spy" programm. This could be implemented as eclipse plugin for example which gathers statics about what files are opened and edited or whatever.

On a side note: Get some sense into your superiors. If they haven't experienced the lack of qualified IT-personel yet, then with a course like this soon they might.

Good project management applies less invasive methods to gather information about progress and effectivity.

Comment: "On a side note: Get some sense into your superiors. If they haven't experienced the lack of qualified IT-personel yet, then with a course like this soon they might." - A toast to that! lol

Answer (score 4):

Free source control systems don't tend to give you this information because they work disconnected from the server - you can 'get' a file, but you don't have to tell the server that you've changed it until you come to check in. This is itself a deliberate feature, as it means that you can work on the road, at home, etc, without being tethered to the central repository.

Locks can be used in subversion to some effect to get similar reporting, but it's not a great solution. They're designed to prevent 2 people modifying a file at the same time, specifically where merges are a problem. That said, they don't actually prevent someone checking in a file without getting the lock, so they're a weak indication at best, not a guarantee.

Also, none of the more modern distributed systems, like git or mercurial can even begin to give you this information, the repositories are on your machine, not centralised, and links back to the original are tenuous as best. Consider - you've got 5 local branches, do you report all the files as being modified against the original, or just the active branch? You can clone repos from already cloned repos, how many levels of abstraction do you follow to get to the 'master' repo? Who decides, and how would you configure what that master is? Git et al can handle all this complexity with great grace, but the question 'who has checked out this file' is almost meaningless in this context.

The old stalwarts like TFS and Perforce do allow this. But I'd be curious why they need this feature, just because someone has a modified copy of a file doesn't really mean anything in management terms, branches can still be protected very effectively using repository security, any task tracking system like trac or redmine will tell you who's doing what and integrate with svn perfectly.

There may be 3rd part applications that look for working copies and upload status information to a central reporting server, but I've not seen one. It might even be worth making one.

Comment: I think it's more for the sake of knowing who has the files. And if I use svn through Apache then it's just a case or parsing the HTTP logs.

I already explained to them that locking is bad and I think it's gotten through to them. As we constantly develop features in parallel.

Then again I have been trying to convince them to use any form of scm for the past 10 years lol