# Is it possible to trace checkout in Subversion?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Is there someway to trace the checkout under Subversion or it is completely untraceable?

Comment: This is already answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804970/is-there-a-subversion-checkout-hook-or-something-similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804970/is-there-a-subversion-checkout-hook-or-something-similar).

Comment: Please elaborate: what information do you want trace about the checkout? It's obviously traceable, in the sense I would define the term, so you must mean something unobvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkout is, like any other network communication, traceable. The repository administrator can simply look into the logfiles of svnserve or apache, or just dump all packets on the link.

Note that you can use svn over [TOR](http://torproject.org/) just fine; unless you use your user name, you're untraceable then.